# Classes code generated from protobuf file not found in Scalapb

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I'm new to Scalapb and currently I'm trying to compile a proto file to Scala classes as below

build.sbt (made by George Leung / phiSgr - run normally on his demo project):

```
// the enterprisePackage task is confused
ThisBuild / Gatling / publishArtifact := false
ThisBuild / GatlingIt / publishArtifact := false

val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.github.phisgr",
  scalaVersion := "2.13.10",
  crossPaths := false,
)

val gatlingVersion = "3.9.5"
val gatlingCore = "io.gatling" % "gatling-core" % gatlingVersion

val publishSettings = {
  import xerial.sbt.Sonatype._
  Seq(
    publishTo := SonatypeKeys.sonatypePublishTo.value,
    publishMavenStyle := true,

    licenses := Seq("APL2" -> url("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt")),
    sonatypeProjectHosting := Some(GitHubHosting("phiSgr", "gatling-grpc", "phisgr@gmail.com")),
  )
}

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(publishSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "gatling-grpc",
    version := "0.16.0",
    inConfig(Test)(sbtprotoc.ProtocPlugin.protobufConfigSettings),
    Test / PB.targets := Seq(
      scalapb.gen() -> (Test / sourceManaged).value,
      PB.gens.java -> (Test / sourceManaged).value,
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:existentials",
      "-language:implicitConversions",
      "-language:higherKinds",
      "-Xlint",
      "-opt:l:method",
    ),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % scalapb.compiler.Version.grpcJavaVersion,
      "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf",
      "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion,
      gatlingCore,
      "com.github.phisgr" % "gatling-ext" % "0.4.0",
      "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % gatlingVersion % "test",
      "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % gatlingVersion % "test",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.12" % "test",
    ),
  )
  .dependsOn(macroSub % "compile-internal")

lazy val macroSub = (project in file("macro"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "macro",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      gatlingCore,
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:experimental.macros",
    ),
  )

// Usually the two update together (for specifying IntelliJ compatibility)
val gatlingJavaPbVersion = "1.3.0"
val gatlingJavaPbExtVersion = gatlingJavaPbVersion
lazy val javaPb = (project in file("java-pb"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(publishSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "gatling-javapb",
    version := gatlingJavaPbVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "3.21.6",
      gatlingCore,
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:implicitConversions",
      "-language:experimental.macros",
    ),
  )
  .dependsOn(root % "test->test")
lazy val bench = (project in file("bench"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .dependsOn(root, javaPb)
  .enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
  .settings(
    Compile / PB.targets := Seq(
      PB.gens.java -> (Compile / sourceManaged).value,
      scalapb.gen() -> (Compile / sourceManaged).value
    ),
  )
  .dependsOn(macroSub % "compile-internal")
```

scalapb.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "1.0.6")

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.11.11"
```

The problem is when I tried to put these files into my new project, the *sbt "compile"* run successfully, but no scala classes are found, is there any settings that I need to make ?

Comment: What does it mean that no Scala classes are found? Is it runtime error that class was not found, or does the compiler fail to find any files to compile and succeeds at compiling 0 files?